# Android BitmapFactory decodeStream()

Tags: android, decode, bitmapfactory, sample-size

I have a question that I seem to find the answer nowhere.
Does this lines of code:

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
```

actually mean that, that file is being downloaded? Android docs say something like this:

> decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions

**and**
Does:

```
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
```

means that it will actually download the file smaller (**not downloaded as original size and copied after that to a smaller size bitmap**).

Clear example: I have some url's that point to many 2000 x 1500 images. By decoding those files and loading them to bitmaps, do I need to have enough memory for downloading the file at its full resolution (2000 x 1500), if I only need thumbnails of (200 x 150)?

Comment: I think you would need to download the full resolution (2000 x 1500) unless the server provides any size reducing parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed looks like the file is being downloaded, and the effiency part comes where the bitmap being loaded in memory is the smaller one ( the one being decoded with inSampleSize options).

Answer (score 2):

I know another answer has already been accepted as the right one but for clarity...

This line `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;` means that the call to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);` doesn't get the bitmap information but does get bounding information and the MimeType.

You can then use these returned values, `outWidth`, `outHeight` and `outMimeType` to get a 'resampled' version of the bitmap data by setting `options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;` and setting the sample size to a given ratio determined by your desired output dimensions `options. inSampleSize = [int]`.

See this very informative page for more information: [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)